# How to delete post item from db by Post id in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with wordpress, I am getting following data in loop,"Id" is our "postid",And i want to delete only single attribute/key(profile_image) using that "postid",which i am getting in loop

```
Array
(
    [id] => 46456
    [status] => approved
    [profile_image] => isProfile
)

Array
(
    [id] => 46457
    [status] => approved
    [profile_image] => isProfile
)

Array
(
    [id] => 46458
    [status] => approved
    [profile_image] => isProfile
)
```

Here is my code,How can i do this ?

```
foreach($datas as $data)
    {
        echo "<pre>";print_r($data);
        delete_metadata( 'post', null, 'profile_image', '', true );
    }
```

Where i am wrong ?

Comment: _"Where i am wrong ?"_ - for one, in asking about this again after you already did so only two hours earlier, [How to delete metadata by user id in wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71919979/how-to-delete-metadata-by-user-id-in-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete post meta using [delete_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_post_meta/) function.

```
forech($posts as $post){
    delete_post_meta($post->ID, 'profile_image');
}
```

Comment: not working for me

Comment: What is not working? Update your question posting result of var_dump.

Comment: My current updated code is 

foreach($datas as $data)
       {
        if (array_key_exists('id', $data))
        {
         delete_post_meta($data['id'], 'profile_image', 'isProfile'); 
        }
       }
      echo "<pre>";print_r($datas);

But showing me same result (profile_image not deleted)

Comment: Usually, it should work. Try once without setting the value. If that still doesn't work, need more  output reference.

Comment: i am getting same output (i mentioned in array )

Comment: Did you try removing value? I mean not setting value parameter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244008/discussion-between-code-lover-and-amit-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress function [delete_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_post_meta/)

```
<?php delete_post_meta(76, 'my_key', 'Steve'); ?>
```

Comment: what is "steve" ? array ?

Comment: `Steve` is a value he placed as a reference to show you.

Comment: My current updated code is 

foreach($datas as $data)
       {
        if (array_key_exists('id', $data))
        {
         delete_post_meta($data['id'], 'profile_image', 'isProfile'); 
        }
       }
      echo "<pre>";print_r($datas);

But showing me same result (profile_image not deleted)

Comment: @AmitSharma update your question with all output.

Comment: @CodeLover: i am getting same output (i mentioned in array )